# Sorting polygon's points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a convex polygon ABCDE... (it can have any number of points). I need to sort all its vertexes so none of the edges will intersect.
example:

```
A _____ B
  \   /
   \ /
    X
   / \
  /___\
C       D
```

That polygon in ABCD order has intersecting edges. however in ABDC order:

```
A _____ B
  |   |
  |   |
  |   |
  |   |
  |___|
C       D
```

None of the edges intersect so ABDC is the expected output.

How can I do this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/828905/310574

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your points are all on the convex hull of your polygon, you can use the following:

1. Pick the two extreme points with the min and max X value, (call them X<sub>min</sub> and X<sub>max</sub>) and draw the line between them.  In the case where you have multiple points with the same X value at the extremes, pick X<sub>min</sub> with the minimum Y value and X<sub>max</sub> with the maximum Y value.
2. Split the list of points into two sub lists where all of the points below the line connecting X<sub>min</sub> and X<sub>max</sub> are in one list and all those above that line are in another.  Include X<sub>min</sub> in the first list and X<sub>max</sub> in the second.
3. Sort the first list in ascending order of X value.  If you have multiple points with the same X value, sort them in ascending Y value.  This should only happen for points with the same X component as X<sub>max</sub> since the polygon is convex.
4. Sort the second list in descending order of X value.  Again, sort in descending Y value in the event of multiple points with the same X value (which should only happen for points with X component X<sub>min</sub>.
5. Append the two lists together (it doesn't matter which is first).

Comment: FYI: There is absolutely no need to use inverse trig functions to radially sort the points.  You can just sort based on the actual value (y - y0)/(x-x0).  That's the kernel of the graham scan

Comment: @Foo Bah:  Thanks for point that out.  It wasn't clear from your answer.  BTW, did you downvote the answer?  If so, why did you edit it?

Comment: I edited it because i wanted to undo my downvote, then forgot to do so afterwards.  I have removed it now.

Answer (score 10):

choose two points on the polygon.  the midpoint of the line will be contained within that polygon.  Let that point be M.

Then, sort the points based on the angle based from M (along the X axis), breaking degeneracy based on distance from M.  Iterating in that order ensures that no two edges will intersect.

Comment: brilliant idea!