# How to create a polygon from 150 points in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created polygon for set of fixed points

```
Polygon myPolygon = new Polygon();

System.Windows.Point Point1 = new System.Windows.Point(50, 100);
System.Windows.Point Point2 = new System.Windows.Point(200, 100);
System.Windows.Point Point3 = new System.Windows.Point(200, 200);
System.Windows.Point Point4 = new System.Windows.Point(300, 30);
PointCollection polygonPoints = new PointCollection();
polygonPoints.Add(Point1);
polygonPoints.Add(Point2);
polygonPoints.Add(Point3);
polygonPoints.Add(Point4);

myPolygon.Points = polygonPoints; 
mygrid.Children.Add(myPolygon);
```

Is it possible to create polygon from dynamic points?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828905/polygon-enclosing-a-set-of-points

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic points"? If `new System.Windows.Point(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are calculated at runtime is a "dynamic point", then that's what you need.

Comment: In the interface i should able to deplace the points to change shape of polygone.